# Rails indentation convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indentation, convention

```
 <%= link_to 'Foo',
 {:contoller  => 'bar',
 :id => 'baz.id' %>
 }
```

There is no consensus amongst my peers as how this should be indented. I'd like to know myself so that I am not writing code the wrong way.

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Usually, the `}` is "indented" to be within the erb block... ;)

Comment: There is no consensus anywhere... indentation is highly personal. Pick something that works for you and your team, and use it consistently.

Answer (score 2):

`<%= link_to 'Foo', use_named_routes_for_crying_out_loud, id: baz.id %>`

Comment: We are working on a legacy database, for crying out loud! There are NO NAMED ROUTES!!!!

Comment: Named routes are not typically limited by the database...

Comment: My point is that it is legacy code from ten years ago and that there aren't any named routes.

Comment: If it is not worth adjusting the code in a trivial way to improve maintainability, it is probably not worth futzing with indentation, either.